# how to change / specify fill color which exceeds the limits of a gradient bar？

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-tile

In ggplot2/geom_tile, how to change fill color whice exceed the limits？
As the image, Region_4/5 are out of `limis(1,11)` , so the fill color is default grey, how to change 'Region_4' to 'darkblue', 'Region_5' to 'black' . Thanks!

```
library(tidyverse)
library(RColorBrewer)
tile_data <- data.frame(category=letters[1:5],
                        region=paste0('region_',1:5),
                        sales=c(1,2,5,0.1,300))


tile_data %>% ggplot(aes(x=category,
                         y=region,
                         fill=sales))+
  geom_tile()+
  scale_fill_gradientn(limits=c(1,11),
                       colors=brewer.pal(12,'Spectral'))+
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your replay . " so- you wanna two different colors for values “off limits” (limits of what)"--right, this is waht i want.  There are the three cut-off  "limits=c(1,11)  limits=c(0,0.9)   limits=c(100,400)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the gradient scale and have two additional discrete values for off limits above and below, I think the easiest way would be to have separate fill scales for "in-limit" and "off-limit" values. This can be done with separate calls to geom_tile on subsets of your data and with packages such as {ggnewscale}.

I think it then would make sense to place the discrete "off-limits" at the respective extremes of your gradient color bar. You need then three `geom_tile` calls and three `scale_fill` calls, and you will need to specify the guide order within each `scale_fill` call. You will then need to play around with the legend margins, but it's not a big problem to make it look OK.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(RColorBrewer)
tile_data <- data.frame(
  category = letters[1:5],
  region = paste0("region_", 1:5),
  sales = c(1, 2, 5, 0.1, 300)
)


ggplot(tile_data, aes(
  x = category,
  y = region,
  fill = sales
)) +
  geom_tile(data = filter(tile_data, sales <= 11 & sales >=1)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(NULL,
    limits = c(1, 11),
    colors = brewer.pal(11, "Spectral"),
    guide = guide_colorbar(order = 2)
  ) +
  ggnewscale::new_scale_fill() +
  geom_tile(data = filter(tile_data, sales > 11), mapping = aes(fill = sales > 11)) +
  scale_fill_manual("Sales", values = "black", labels = "> 11", guide = guide_legend(order = 1)) +
  ggnewscale::new_scale_fill() +
  geom_tile(data = filter(tile_data, sales < 1), mapping = aes(fill = sales < 1)) +
  scale_fill_manual(NULL, values = "darkblue", labels = "< 1", guide = guide_legend(order = 3)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.spacing.y = unit(-6, "pt"), 
        legend.title = element_text(margin = margin(b = 10)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-11-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: 'ggnewscale'  is  exactly what I want , great ,Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can try [scales::squish](https://scales.r-lib.org/reference/squish.html), define the limits, and put the out of bound (oob) values into the scalw:

```
p = tile_data %>% ggplot(aes(x=category,y=region,fill=sales))+ geom_tile()
p + scale_fill_gradientn(colors = brewer.pal(11,"Spectral"),
limit = c(1,11),oob=scales::squish)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your replay , this is a new useful knowledge for me .  Is there way to define the fill colors?

Comment: what do you mean by define fill colors? You have already done it with  `colors = brewer.pal(11,"Spectral")` can you be a bit more specific,

Comment: I want to define the fill color  'Region_4' > 'darkblue', 'Region_5' > 'black'  . Thanks!

Comment: hey that doesn't work. you are using a continuous color scheme. Region 4 has a value of 0.1 so it should be more red, and yes you can make region 5 black by doing `colors = c(brewer.pal(11,"Spectral"),"#000000")`

Comment: Thanks for your replay.  I will try to use   'colors = c(brewer.pal(11,"Spectral"),"#000000")' , this is new knowledge for me.